# Trying to Understand ConstrainedBox

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, width

Flutter Newbie here.

Please refer to this example from Flutter docs [Example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html#widgets.SingleChildScrollView.1)

I have added just **4 lines to that code**. You will find those lines which has comment "Lines Added by me".
But **there is no change in the output**.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
          print(viewportConstraints.minWidth);     // Lines Added By me
          print(viewportConstraints.maxWidth);     // Lines Added By me
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                maxWidth : viewportConstraints.minWidth/2,  // Lines Added By me
                minWidth : viewportConstraints.minWidth/2,  // Lines Added By me
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    // A fixed-height child.
                    color: const Color(0xffeeee00), // Yellow
                    height: 120.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text('Fixed Height Content'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    // Another fixed-height child.
                    color: const Color(0xff008000), // Green
                    height: 120.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text('Fixed Height Content'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

So I am just playing with that example. And i wanted to see that if i can control the width of containers by providing maxWidth to constrainedBox. But its not working and i want to know reason/concept behind that?

Now in section *layout behaviour* of [container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) says that "If the widget has an alignment, and the parent provides bounded constraints, then the Container tries to expand to fit the parent, and then positions the child within itself as per the alignment."

Can someone explain me where i am wrong in my understanding ?

[image]

From the above ScreenShot it seems that proper(width/2) constraints are not passed to column.

Comment: Is this correct `maxWidth : viewportConstraints.minWidth/2,`? Here you passed `minWidth/2`.

Comment: yes. Just making it a tight constraint

Answer (score 0):

What's the expected behavior here when you mentioned that there's no change in the output? `LayoutBuilder.builder()` returns an updated constraints if there's change in Screen (i.e. screen rebuild). As for adjusting the size of `ConstrainedBox` using `BoxConstraints`, what you're doing here is setting the min and max dimension of the parent Widget, not setting the dimension of the parent Widget. If the children are larger than the parent, then it will be constrained by the set dimensions.